# Prove that $\mathbb{R}[x]/{(x^2-1)}\cong\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-spaces

> Prove that $\mathbb{R}[x]/{(x^2-1)}\cong\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$

As my attempt: since $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$

this means  $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x-1)\cong \mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}[x]/(x+1)\cong \mathbb{R},$

Comment: Perhaps this is beyond the scope of your knowledge, but the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) seems relevant. Check out the section titled "Generalization to arbitrary rings".

Comment: Also, you really ought to be specifying whether this isomorphism is an isomorphism of rings or of some other algebraic object.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the map 
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha:R[x]/(x^2-1)&\longrightarrow&R\times R\\
f(x)&\mapsto&(f(1),f(-1))
\end{array}

You can check $\alpha$ is an isomorphism, i.e.  bijection and homomorphism.

Comment: This hits the nail on the head. To add context to this answer, this isomorphism is exactly what applying the Chinese Remainder Theorem gives (after the proper identifications of $\frac{R[x]}{(x-1)} \cong R$ and $\frac{R[x]}{(x+1)} \cong R$).

Answer (score 2):

Note that the ideals $I_1=\langle x-1\rangle$ and $I_2=\langle x+1 \rangle$ are co-prime since $1=\dfrac{x+1}{2}-\dfrac{x-1}{2}\in I_1+I_2$.

Also $I=I_1\cap I_2=\langle x^2-1\rangle$.

Hence by Chinese Remainder Theorem,

> $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2-1\rangle=\Bbb R[x]/I\cong \Bbb R[x]/I_1\times \Bbb R[x]/I_2=\Bbb R[x]/\langle x-1\rangle \times \Bbb R[x]/\langle x+1\rangle \cong \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$

Comment: I didn't downvote, because it was an honest mistake. But, the polynomial in question was $x^2-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-1)=\mathbb R[x]/(x-1)(x+1)=\mathbb R[x]/(x-1) \times \mathbb R[x]/(x+1) \cong \mathbb R \times \mathbb R $ where

$(x-1)$ is maximal ideal in $\mathbb R[x]$, then $R[x]/(x-1)\cong \mathbb R[1]=\mathbb R$, and similar way we have $R[x]/(x+1)\cong \mathbb R[-1]=\mathbb R$

we have $x^2+1=(x-1)(x+1)$, then $\mathbb R[x]/(x-1)(x+1)=\mathbb R[x]/(x-1) \times \mathbb R[x]/(x+1)$

Comment: Are you doing anything but copying the asker's own attempt? Without explanations?

Comment: ok, I edit my answer.