# Show a ring isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to show there is an isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In the solution provided in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2132888/1092334, it is $(f(1),f(-1))$ for $f\in \mathbb{R}[x]$.

I can show the homomorphic property, but not surjectivity.

I should take $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and show there is a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ for which $f(1)=a, f(-1)=b$. Am I right?

Comment: What about $f(x)=\frac12((a-b)x+a+b)$?

Comment: That's right. For a hint, use the polynomial $f(x)=mx+c$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos how did you find it so quickly?!

Comment: It was clear that there should be a solution with degree $1$. So, I took $f(x)=\alpha(x-1)+a$, which is such that $f(1)=a$. And then I solved the equation $f(-1)=b$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks!

Comment: @Mike it's the same I link in my question :) I wanted to comment there on the answer, but I don't have enough reputation! I have to ask a new question

Comment: Submitted multiple times my claim that it is not a duplicate question. Didn't go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both rings are 2 dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$.   So write down what $f$ does as a matrix and check that it has rank 2.

If you identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with column vectors, then you have:
\begin{equation}
f(ax+b) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\-1 &  1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a \\b\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

You can then trivially perform [gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), to determine this matrix has [full rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)), and is therefore surjective.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "check rank 2"? I don't know this method

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. I will study your method. I have to delete my question because it has been flagged as duplicate, incorrectly, regardless of my multiple attempts to make it clear it was not a duplicate. Nevermind, I can't even delete it

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: @BillDubuque I still believe my question is not a duplicate: first, I link in my post the question someone thought this was a duplicate of; also I'm asking "help me prove there is a surjective function such that...". Perhaps the title is wrong; I made it clear the intention was to find an isomorphism and where my problem came from. I couldn't find a way to prove surjectivity as in the linked question, and I could not (due to low reputation) comment there. I did not mean to post any duplicate answer. I am now allowed by the website to delete this question.